# How to install Scrapy in PyCharm?

Tags: scrapy, pycharm

I want to install the Scrapy package in PyCharm, but this error occurs everytime:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:


ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\HP\scrapingenv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0h3rlipy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\HP\scrapingenv\include\site\python3.8\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: If you are on windows, please try [the officially recommended way using Anaconda or Miniconda](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).

Answer (score 1):

On the terminal, navigate to the desired folder, try running the below command :

```
pip install scrapy
```

Just keep trying to install multiple times as it worked for me.